# Laravel PHP Unit - Keep output from tests

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

### TLDR;

How can I run php unit tests in Laravel 7 without removing all output that is emitted during the execution of a test?

### Full question:

I'm trying to run a few tests in Laravel 7 with PHPUnit 8.5.

In these tests, I am dumping information as the test isn't simply pass or fail, but dumping further information to help improve page load efficiency. For this reason, I am dumping this data into the terminal.

Data is dumped into the terminal while the test is running, but once the test has been completed, the information is removed.

**Problem**: I would like to prevent this output from being removed.

**Attempted solutions that did not work:**

- `--verbose`
- `--debug`
- `--no-interaction`
- turn on strict mode within phpunit
- dump information using the fwrite() method
- ob_flush()
- print_r()
- print()

Note: I realise that this topic has been discussed previously, but none of those methods are currently working.

Comment: If the problem is that the output is lost due to the way the running is "animated" then you can try `--no-interaction` to disable said animation

Comment: Hi @apokryfos, I tried `--no-interaction`, for example `php artisan test --no-interaction`. Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem :'(